# CORS Issue on Ionic CLI 6.13.0

Tags: php, ionic-framework, cors, preflight

I'm trying to make an http post request in `ionic` with `php` on  backend,..

Here's my code in ionic :

```
        let body = {
            'data': ['data [0]', 'data [1]']
        };
        let options = {
            headers : { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' }
        };
        const ifSuccess = (response) => {
            console.log(response);
            this.data = response;
        };
        const ifFail = (response) => {
            this.error = 'Oops! Une erreur au niveau du serveur...';
        };
        this.http.post('http://localhost/cantine-itu/test', body, options).subscribe(ifSuccess, ifFail);
```

Here's the backend (in php flight) :

```
Flight::before('json', function () {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8100');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
});

Flight::route('POST /test', function(){
    $data = Flight::request()->data;
    Flight::json($data);
});
```

I'm getting an error saying that : `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/cantine-itu/test' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
([error-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GevnA.png))

Comment: Try putting the headers at the top of your php file.

Comment: I tried that, but nothing changed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting this error from web browser or a particular device?

Since this is local development and not production I would set to the most permissive possible.

```
  'capacitor://localhost',
  'ionic://localhost',
  'http://localhost',
  'http://localhost:8080',
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/cors